# I can't run the flask server in react project it shows this sh: 1: venv/bin/flask: not found error

Tags: reactjs, flask, vite, npm-scripts

I made a react project and flask for APIs .

This the structure of my project

```
.
├── api
├── index.html
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
├── README.md
├── src
└── vite.config.js
```

I have defined a custom script in the `package.json` to run the server
`"start-api": "cd api && venv/bin/flask run --no-debugger",`

but it shows this error when I run it

```
npm run start-api

> flaskreact@0.0.0 start-api
> cd api && venv/bin/flask run --no-debugger

sh: 1: venv/bin/flask: not found
```

It used to work, but this time no
I haven't change any thing

Comment: actualy it worked, i reinstall the venv and install the requirements libs.
The thing that i want to know is why this ? or if they are any other solution, you are welcome to answer.